# I want the object to move in different directions

Tags: javascript

I can't figure out how to make the object move first from right to left, and then as soon as it got to the left side, it immediately started moving in the other direction

```
var tm;
var cars;
var cx;
var gameBegin;

function go()
{
    if(gameBegin==1) return;
    gameBegin = 1;
    cars = new Array();
    for (var i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        cars[i] = document.getElementById("p"+i);
        cars[i].style.border = "none";
    }
    cx = new Array();
    for (var i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        cx[i] = 680;
    }
    tm = window.setInterval(timerGo, 50);
}

function timerGo()
{
    for (var i=0; i<5; i++)
    {

        cx[i] = cx[i] - Math.floor((Math.random()*7+2))
        if (cx[i]<=0)
        {
            window.clearInterval(tm);
            gameBegin = 0;
            cars[i].style.border = "5px ridge yellow";
            return;
        }
        cars[i].style.left = ""+cx[i]+"px";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll create a simpler example using a single object, and you can then extend it out to an arbitrary number of objects.  I will approach this by tracking a "directionMultiplier", which will be initialized to -1, signaling a negative, or left-moving direction, and then once the position of the object is <= 0, the direction multiplier will be reset to a positive 1.

```js
var direction = -1;
var object = document.getElementById("object");
var position = 350;
var speed = 20;

function go(){
    object.style.left = position+"px";
    setInterval(tick, 50);
}

function tick(){
  position += direction * speed;
  if (position < 0)
  {
    position = 0;
    direction = 1;
  }
  if (position > 350)
  {
    position = 350;
    direction = -1;
  }
  object.style.left = position + "px";
}

go();
```

```css
.container{
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.object{
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="object" class="object">
  
  </div>
</div>
```

I hard-coded a lot of my sizes in my example, which isn't great practice but helps keep the code simpler.

Since you said you're making a game, a JS solution may indeed be your best bet, but I will also mention that you could consider using the CSS `animation` property with `@keyframes` to create a simple back & forth animation as well, depending on your needs.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but when the object reaches the finish line, it is highlighted with a yellow frame and the objects come randomly, and the timer stops.

Comment: I thought the question was asking how you can make the object move left and right across the screen?  Is there also a stopping and visual component to your question?  If so can you update your question with more details?

Answer (score 0):

**Box move left to right and right to left** :

```js
let box = document.querySelector(".box");
      let counter = 0,
        timeFrame = 60,
        bool = true;

      function init() {
        box.style.left = counter + "px";

        if (bool) counter += timeFrame / 2;
        if (!bool) counter -= timeFrame / 2;

        if (counter > 500) bool = false;
        if (counter < 0) bool = true;
      }

      setInterval(init, timeFrame);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Good</title>
  </head>
  <style>
    .box {
      position: absolute;
      background-color: yellow;
      height: 200px;
      width: 200px;
      transition: 0.1s;
    }
  </style>
  <body>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```